# How to set "nojoinspaces" in evil mode

Tags: evil, doom

In vim, you can `:set nojoinspaces` to prevent `J` from adding a space when joining lines that end in a period. How do I set this in evil mode? I'm using Doom emacs, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the function `evil-join-whitespace`, and a key binding
for that. In normal Emacs + evil, this is `g J`.

In your case, you need to add a suitable key, e.g `C-c J`, with some code
in your `~/doom.d/config.el` or where the `config.el` file is:

```lisp
(evil-define-key* 'normal 'global
    (kbd "C-c J" #'evil-join-whitespace))
;; or this:
(after! evil
    (map! :n "C-c J" #'evil-join-whitespace))
```

See the files `~/.emacs.d/docs/faq.org` and `~/.emacs.d/docs/examples.org`.
NB: not tested.

Comment: Thanks! I've just mapped `J` to `evil-join-whitespace`, and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am unable to reproduce the behavior (of `evil-join` adding an extra space after a period), here is a solution that should emulate vim's `nojoinspace` behavior.

Inspecting the function `evil-join` we find that it uses the function `join-line` without adding the option for 'nojoinspaces functionality'. Also, `join-line` (which is an alias for `delete-indentation`) does not offer such functionality. However, I would say such functionality can be added by [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) either `evil-join` or `join-line`.

It is not straightforward to create a 'succesful' advice for `evil-join` or `join-line` when applying it to multiple lines. Luckily, when applying `evil-join` to multiple lines, it simply applies `join-line` to a single line multiple times. Therefore, it is easiest to simply advise `join-line` e.g. as follows

```lisp
(defun evil-nojoinspaces-ad (&rest _)
    (when (looking-back "\\.")
        (delete-char 1)))

(advice-add 'delete-indentation :after #'evil-nojoinspaces-ad)
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `evil-join-whitespace` command of @Ian's answer. Thanks @Ian